# How to clear timeout in React upon state change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, timer, settimeout, alert

I have a React alert component which renders a Modal. There are two ways for the modal to close either by manually pressing close or if the modal is not closed by pressing close then the modal should close automatically by X seconds

hideAlert() is called when the modal is closed
So far both works however if the modal is closed by the user, hideAlert() will be called twice - from the method called after pressing close and inside setTimeout().

Probably simple enough my question is how do I cancel the timer that will call hideAlert() if the modal was already closed by the user?

p.s. when hideAlert() is called this dispatches an action to Redux and the reducer sets the state to:

```
        case LandingActionTypes.HideAlert:
            return { 
                ...state, 
                ...{ 
                    alertMessage: {
                        title: '',
                        message: ''
                    },
                    showAlert: false,
                    type: "danger" as MessageType,
                    icon: "danger" as MessageType,
                    autoHide: true,
                    duration: 5000
                } 
            }
```

I've tried to clear the timeout by checking state change using useEffect() without success

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!showAlert) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    }
}, [showAlert])
```

Full component code

Thanks

```
// @ts-ignore
import Modal from "modal-enhanced-react-native-web";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { MessageType } from "react-native-flash-message";
import { IAlertMessage } from '../../models/IAlertMessage';
import { HideAlertAction } from '../../state/contexts/alert/Actions';
import styles from "./styles";

export interface IPropsFromState {
    alertMsg: IAlertMessage
    showAlert: boolean
    type?: MessageType
    icon?: MessageType
    autoHide?: boolean
    duration?: number
}

export interface IPropsFromDispatch {
    hideAlert: typeof HideAlertAction.creator
}

type AllProps = IPropsFromState & IPropsFromDispatch

const AlertMessage: React.FC<AllProps> = (props) => {

    let timer: any

    const {
        alertMsg,
        type,
        icon,
        showAlert,
        autoHide,
        duration,
        hideAlert,
    } = props

    if (!showAlert) {
        return null
    }

    const {
        title,
        message,
        cancelText,
        confirmText
    } = alertMsg

    useEffect(() => {
        if (autoHide) {
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                hideAlert()
            }, duration)
        }
    }, [alertMsg])

    const renderButton = (text: string) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={hideAlert}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Text>{text}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    const renderModalContent = () => (
        <View style={styles.modalContent}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 10 }}>{title}</Text>
            <Text>{message}</Text>
            {renderButton("Close")}
        </View>
    );

    console.log("*[ALERT] " + JSON.stringify(alertMsg, null, 2))

    return (
        <Modal
            style={styles.bottomModal}
            isVisible={showAlert}
            animationIn="slideInDown"
            animationOut="slideOutUp"
            onBackdropPress={hideAlert}
        >
            {renderModalContent()}
        </Modal>
    );


}

export default AlertMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved changed useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (autoHide) {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!showAlert) return;

            hideAlert()
        }, duration)

        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
}, [alertMsg, showAlert])
```

and moved just before the render method.

```
if (!showAlert) {
    return null
}
```